# Element of pencil of divisor generically irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $S$ be a complex algebraic surface and let $D_{\lambda}$ be a pencil of curves without fixed part  and with an irreducible and reduced divisor in it
 I would like to see an analytic (or just related to complex geometry not more general schematic fact) proof of the following fact (which I've seen called as the Bertini extended theorem):

The generic element of $D_{\lambda}$ is an irreducible divisor.

I tried to emulate the proof of the Bertini theorem about smoothness but I did not make up anything.

Comment: There exists pencils without fixed points with all members reducible. I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Sorry could you show me an example? I' trying to figure out but I did not manage to. I edited the question adding the hypothesis that not all are reducible.

Comment: For an example as I said, take $S=C\times\mathbb{P}^1$ and the map $S\to \mathbb{P}^1$ given by $(x,[a:b])\mapsto [a^2,b^2]$. Then the general fiber is reducible. With your added hypothesis (when you presumably mean, at least  one member of the pencil is reduced and irreducible), the claim is correct.

Comment: Ok thank you for the counterexample. What I should've written is the edited question which I really do not know how to prove